# How to judge whether two context are the same in Android？

Tags: android

such as you want to judge two strings, you can use string1.equals(string2)...then how to judge  whether  two context are the same in Android？

Comment: Why do you need to compare two contexts? I cannot imagine an example.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you do this?

If they are all Activity instances you can treat them as such and use:

```
if ( activity instanceof MyClassActivityOne ) {
// do something 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check it like this

```
if(c1.getClass().equals(c2.getClass()))
{
//The context is the same
}
else
{
//Context is different
}
```

Comment: You just compare that c1 and c2 are instances of the same class. This does not mean that they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the getApplicationContext() of each to see if they are the same.

Comment: Sharing the same Application Context does not mean that they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure,but you can try this:

```
 if(context1.getClass().getName().equals("com.xxx.sameclass"))&&context2.getClass().getName().equals("com.xxx.sameclass")))
{
    if(context1 == context2)
       //same condition
}
```